# If and else If priority if both exist

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a query on a Cloud CKRecord, which checks to see if a documents exists (i.e. has been uploaded as an CKAsset) and if not checks if a URL exists (i.e. has been uploaded as a String). All works well if either exist on their own for a given record, however if both exist when clicking on the link nothing happens.

I feel it is something to do with the if and else if statements -

```
if filename1 != nil {
    let asset1 = record.object(forKey: "courseDocument1") as? CKAsset
    let filename = record.object(forKey: "courseDocument1Filename") as! String
    let path = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(filename)
    let doc1Data : NSData? = NSData(contentsOf:(asset1?.fileURL)!)
    do {
        try doc1Data!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.courseDoc1WebView?.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        self.venueDocButton1.setTitle(cseDocument1,for: [])
        self.venueDocButton1.isHidden = false
        self.courseDocumentLabel.isHidden = false
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }                        
} else if cseDocument1URL != nil && filename1 == nil {
    let url1 = URL (string: cseDocument1URL!)
    let request1 = URLRequest(url: url1! as URL );
    self.courseDoc2WebView.loadRequest(request1 as URLRequest);
    self.venueDocButton1.setTitle(cseDocument1,for: [])
    self.venueDocButton1.isHidden = false
    self.courseDocumentLabel.isHidden = false
} else {
    print("No Document Found")
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a good case for using the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on your `if` line and step through the code, examining the variables as you go.

Comment: Note that your `else if` statement does not need the `&& filename1 == nil` part. Your code will only evaluate the else clause if the first if statement evaluates as false.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a simple typo rather than logic -

```
self.courseDoc2WebView.loadRequest(request1 as URLRequest);
```

which should actually be -

```
self.courseDoc1WebView.loadRequest(request1 as URLRequest);
```

This was solved by printing responses and using the debugger - thanks Phillip Mills

Duncan C, you make a good point too - thank-you.